# How to give an application with a modifed Info.plist access to the microphone?

Tags: macos, system-settings, microphone

I have an application which requests access to the microphone, and when I accept everything works as it should. But I want to hide from the dock (to have it run in the background sort of). To do this I add this:

```
<key>NSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
```

to the Info.plist. Once I do this, the application hides from the Dock as I want, but the microphone doesn't work. I assume this is because macOS matches the Info.plist (or a checksum of the entire application or something) against the one I initially gave access to microphone, and detects they are not the same and thus blocks it. Is there anyway to work around this?

This used to work in High Sierra, but not now on Mojave 10.14.6.

If I open the executable file through the Terminal, the microphone does work (since I gave Terminal access to the microphone), but then there's still an application in the Dock (which my goal is to hide).

Comment: @user3439894 10.14.6, will add this to the question

Comment: Look in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy to see where the target app has permission, remove the app, run the app again.

Comment: BTW, If you can't reset the app's permissions from System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Microphone, then in Terminal try: `tccutil reset AppName`